Laravel 11 & Inertia Permissions - frontend question
I have experience with Laravel 5 but i've just created a new application with Laravel 11 using Breeze, Inertia & Vue.
I have followed this tutorial at Medium.com.
I'm trying to get the application to display a Create Task button based on if the logged user has the correct permission to view this button.
I have setup the tables as per the tutorial.  The logged in user has the correct permissions set in the database.




This code has been added to the HandleInertiaRequest middleware:
/**
 * Define the props that are shared by default.
 *
 * @return array<string, mixed>
 */
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        ...parent::share($request),
        'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
            'can' => $request->user()?->loadMissing('roles.permissions')
                ->roles->flatMap(function ($role) {
                    return $role->permissions;
                })->map(function ($permission) {
                    return [$permission['title'] => auth()->user()->can($permission['title'])];
                })->collapse()->all(),
        ],
    ];
}

However, when I try to output the Create Task button for the user, it does not show:
<div class="mb-4" v-if="$page.props.auth.can.task_create">
<Link :href="route('tasks.create')" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white border border-transparent font-bold px-4 py-2 text-xs uppercase tracking-widest rounded-md">
    Create
</Link>

The value of $page.props.auth.can.task_create always shows as false.
Does anyone know what I am missing?

Have you tried any debugging? Like putting console.log($page.props.auth) to see what value is making it to the page?

I haven’t tried that yet, I tried var_dump from the HandleInertiaRequest middleware and it was outputting false for all the permission values? Where should I try the console.log?

I would recommend you trying on Tinker. Something like App\Models\User::find(1)->loadMissing... and see what is the output.

dont you have Vue devtools browser extension? you should be able to see in there the props value return from laravel by Inertia
